# Android: I cannot remove elevation / shadow on my toolbar

Tags: android

Hi i would like to remove the elevation and shadow effect from my toolbar for API 21 and greater. Below is what i have tried

```
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

My Toolbar in XML. I have tried to set elevation to 0dp

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
    >
```

And this is ToolbarStyle if it helps

```
<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

**Edit 1: Tried the following in styles v21. Still same result**

```
<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```

**Edit 2: Where the toolbar is in my layout**

```
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can do that with an easy step. Don't remove the `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` from your layout, instead add the attribute `app:elevation="0dp"` to it. Your final layout will be:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp">
            ...
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: When I do this the toolbar disappears completely.

Comment: Please, let me know your layout hierarchy. This way I can assist you.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Don't know how you fixed it, but one way to fix it is with `findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout).bringToFront();`.

Comment: interestingly `android:elevation="0dp"` did not do the trick (on SDK 21+ Device)

Comment: android:elevation doesn't work. For a best result use android:stateListAnimator="@null"

Comment: dont forget to add also findViewById(R.id.appBar).bringToFront();   https://stackoverflow.com/a/41931318/2736039

Comment: just leave it, this is hacky, a change to the implementation of `bringToFront()` could easily undo this

Comment: For MaterialToolBar ```android:elevation="0dp"``` works instead of ```app:elevation```

Comment: app:elevation="0dp" instead of android:elevation="0dp" worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

This remove elevation on toolbar (android:stateListAnimator="@null"), stateListAnimator is for API level 21 or higher, so insert a tools prop (before namespace declaration) like this:

```
//xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" in parent or start element

     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null" 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        tools:targetApi="21">

 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

//your content goes here like RecyclerView, Card or other layout
```

> Here is my sample result:

[image]

Comment: I liked this layout.

Answer (score 9):

Use `setOutlineProvider(null);` on your appBar. Just be sure to check the SDK version. :)

Answer (score 7):

Use `app:elevation="0dp"` in your AppBarLayout. Make sure you put Toolbar inside your AppBarLayout like this -

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:elevation="0dp"> 

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/firstOption"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and add this line to your activity - `findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout).bringToFront();` 
This will bring the AppBar to front.

Answer (score 5):

Just remove this part of you layout hierarchy:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

It's responsible for creating shadow. Toolbar itself doesn't cast any shadow.

Comment: If you add elevation=0dp to AppBarLayout, it goes away.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the activity you want to remove the ActionBar's Elevation.
Before setContent(....), request the ActionBar feature(That is if you have not declared it directly)

```
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

or else just call the declared Toolbar variable
e.g 
     toolbar.setElevation(0);

Answer (score 4):

Get the appbarlayout in code:

```
var appbarLayout = findviewbyid<AppBarLayout>(resource.id.  );
```

set the property

```
appbarLayout.StateListAnimator=null;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see 'Help' at the top right of the answer window to see how to format code.

Comment: Thank you Martin Evans.I will follow the same as you specified

Answer (score 2):

Create another style for v21 and add

`<item name="android:elevation">@dimen/toolbar_elevation</item>` to that style. On normal style don't use elevation and don't use it in xml, just use `style="@style/yourCustomToolbarStyle"`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I made the change but the problem still occurs. Please see my edit for the code

Comment: This is my xml for custom Toolbar:
`<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:background="@color/light_gray">`

where is style-v21 I have elevation for 4dp and no elevation for normal style

Comment: So i should set 4dp elevation on the v21 style version of ToolbarStyle?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your toolbar parent.
I have `<style name="MyName" parent="">` and I use `<item name="popupTheme">` and `<item name="theme">`

Comment: Yeah it could be, i set the elevation to 1000dp :P and removing the getSupportActionBar().setElevation(o) line. The elevation stayed the same. I will post the parent where the toolbar is the child

Comment: oops  you meant style parent. I will try that now, i posted more code in case in the problem is there.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple. Just add following line into your AppBar layout. No need to add elevation for the Toolbar or AppBar layout after this.

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

Answer (score 1):

use  **android:outlineSpotShadowColor=" assign transparent colour"** your shadow will disappear its work for my as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3u1P.png)

Answer (score 0):

To remove elevation by using java code use the line below...

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Comment: Where does this line have to be implemented? Please further explain.

Comment: just below setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); on onCreate() method.