# Set elevation still display shadow below ActionBar in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-actionbar

Inside `values/styles.xml` I have set  `<item name="elevation">0dp</item>` to my `AppTheme` style. and inside `values-21/styles.xml` I have set `<item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>` and I Have also try this
`<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>`.I have also try to `Clean` the Project and `Rebuild` the Project. and also try to `Invalidate Caches and Restart`. But my Emulator still display shadow see the below screen.

**Question :**

How to remove that shadow below to `ActionBar`.

**ScreenShot :**

[image]

Comment: undo all of those u describe on your question and put `android:elevation="0dp"` on your XML layout on the Toolbar element.

Comment: @Budius I am using `ActionBar` and I try this but not work.

Comment: meokrvrenref rfe freiuvrwnei ewfwfijweofewfew fewfjewoifew http://stackoverflow.com/a/34348138

Comment: ActionBar is deprecated. Long-live the Toolbar

Comment: @Budius Where is documentation. and set it now it's work only the shadow create problem for me.

Comment: here http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html and here https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/LNyDnnBYJ8r The G+ post title is "ActionBarActivity is dead, long live AppCompatActivity". In the blog post you'll see the comment that "ActionBarActivity has been deprecated" which you can confirm here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html

Comment: @Budius visit this `ActionBar` is not deprecated. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html

Comment: But as you can see, it's not an actual view. It's just an abstract class that wraps around a Toolbar contained in the activity layout. This only creates issues, like the one you're having. By ditching this abstraction layer and directly accessing the element you have much better control over it.

Comment: @Budius Ok Let's see if Someone Found solution then it's ok otherwise I go to the latest with `Toolbar`.

Comment: The solution using theme will be sometihng similar to what @pdegand59 said.

Comment: @Budius see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why `elevation` is not work in `style`. but When I set it programatically It's just work fine.

```
 getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Same for me... no clue why this is a thing.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a pure ActionBar, and not a Toolbar. This is how you do it :

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/FlatActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="FlatActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
  <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: According to your question, you used `elevation` inside the app theme. This must be used inside a custom style applied to `actionBarStyle`

Comment: @Ironman try to use different approach:
StateListAnimator stateListAnimator = new StateListAnimator();
 stateListAnimator.addState(new int[0], ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(appBarLayout, "elevation", 0));
 appBarLayout.setStateListAnimator(stateListAnimator);

Answer (score 0):

Put your toolbar in this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        ...

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: I am not using `ToolBar`.