# Cannot remove shadow from action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I simply want to remove the shadow from the toolbar in the app bar layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
           android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
           app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
           app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
           android:elevation="0dp"/>


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
           android:id="@+id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:tabMode="fixed"
           app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I've tried a several approaches to removing the shadow all with no observable effect

I've tried setting the elevation programmatically in my main activity class

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

I've tried setting an attribute in my app theme style

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

I tried

```
app:elevation="0dp"
android:elevation="0dp"
```

I have no idea why none of these approaches have no effect

Comment: Change the style of app bar layout into your custom style.

Comment: You mean change `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar` how so?

Comment: are you use this `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` for import.

Comment: @Ironman What do you mean?

Comment: @the_prole post complete `xml` file in the question .

Comment: @Ironman ok i have posted it

Comment: @the_prole your code is perfect try to clean again and if you are using `Android Studio` then go to `File > Invalidate Caches and Restart`. I have the same Problem here by writing programatically solve the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37985505/set-elevation-still-display-shadow-below-actionbar-in-android

Comment: Yes ! customize that particular style or add app:elevation="0dp" in AppBarLayout.

Comment: @RanjanaDangol I already tried app:elevation="0dp" in AppBarLayout

Comment: did you try setting the background color for appbar layout?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact code in one my apps and it works perfectly. There is one minor change, I have added this attribute - `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```