# when set app:elevation="0dp" then hamburgermenu not showing to toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appbarlayout, hamburger-menu

Hi I wanted to remove the below shadow of toolbar for that I have used elevation property,
Currently my code is

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and the output is:-

[image]

here I dont want the below shadow so I set

```
    app:elevation="0dp"
```

to AppBarLayout, 
then it removes the shadow but the HamburgerMenu disappeared.
the new output is as below:-
[image]

Can anybody tell me how do I remove the shadow without hiding/disappearing HamburgerMenu .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp">
            ...
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

then in your activity;

```
findViewById(R.id.appBar).bringToFront();
```