# Navigation drawer is not opening when set app:elevation="0dp" in AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I want to implement Navigation drawer it's working well but when i set **app:elevation="0dp"** in **AppBarLayout** at that time the navigation drawer is not opening. i have tried folowing code.

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                LOGD("Clicked:::","Drawer");
            }
        });
```

and also using toggle

```
drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar,
                R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
        drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        drawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
```

but it's not working, i stuck from many days, pls help to solve it!!!

Comment: Any idea about it?

Comment: You have to pass the menu Layout in the openDrawer method rather than the gravity.

Comment: Why don't you use drawerlayout ?

Comment: Add your xml code which includes AppBarLayout element.

Comment: I also facing this problem. Did u find solution?? I found that removing app:elevation do open the menu.

Comment: This fixed issue **[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41931245/when-set-appelevation-0dp-then-hamburgermenu-not-showing-to-toolbar)**