# Remove android.widget.Toolbar shadow

Tags: java, android, android-styles

Using API21+ `Toolbar`:

```
// Toolbar
Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar(this);
toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
```

Would like to remove its shadow completely. `setElevation(0)` doesn't do anything since `getElevation()` already returns `0`.

There is Material Design reference:

https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-toolbars

There is Develop Reference:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

But I don't see any info related to the shadow. `Toolbar`

**Question:** how to remove/hide `Toolbar` shadow completely?

Comment: Did you try `app:elevation="0dp"` in your xml? please notice to `app:`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have found solution myself:

```
getActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

More info:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getActionBar()

Answer (score 146):

Use `app:elevation="0dp"` instead of `android:elevation` on your toolbar.
If it is not work, put your toolbar inside of a `AppBarLayout` and set `app:elevation="0dp"`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp">
            ...
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: using this toolbar completely diappeared

Comment: aditionaly add `android:translationZ="0.1dp"`
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50775140/2347168

Answer (score 93):

Use attribute `app:elevation="0dp"` to your `Toolbar` or `AppBarLayout` to remove the shadow.

**#.** If you are using `Toolbar` only, then add attribute `app:elevation="0dp"` to `Toolbar`.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp"/>
```

**#.** If you are using `AppBarLayout` as a container of `Toolbar`, then add attribute `app:elevation="0dp"` to `AppBarLayout`.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

If you want to remove it programmatically then you can use below code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: I have a feeling its highly affected by the compiled sdk version...Still testing though whats your sdk version FAT? Coz am using 26.0.1

Comment: app:elevation="0dp" works fine but  android:elevation="0dp" not!

Comment: The question was for android.widget.Toolbar and not for android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar!

Comment: it completely removes the toolbar, not the shadow

Comment: perfect answer!

Answer (score 41):

Instead of `android:elevation` try `app:elevation`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"       
    app:elevation="0dp">
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 15):

If you are using AppBarLayout in toolbar, you can use:
`app:elevation="0dp"`
instead of
`android:elevation` in AppBarLayout

Answer (score 11):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  appBarLayout.outlineProvider = null
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout).bringToFront();
```

Worked for me version issues I think Thanks [Bjorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561139/bj%c3%b8rn-stenfeldt)

in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247041/android-i-cannot-remove-elevation-shadow-on-my-toolbar)

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in `Fragment` in which you want to hide the `ToolBar`.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set "**#00000000**"  to the backgroundColor of toolbar , 
remember that:
if you use CoordinatorLayout and AppBarLayout ,you should remove the
 
`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

of your contentView ,  I have made this elementary mistake.

Comment: if you are using flags u must use view_behaviour

Answer (score 0):

When you add elevation 0dp on your appbarlayout, toolbar will be completely diappeared.
So that you should also add translationZ in your xml.

```
android:translationZ="0.1dp"
app:elevation="0dp"
```

Than it will look like ->

```
  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:translationZ="0.1dp"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    >

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```